# Vue 3 property value does not exists

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I just started a new project with new installation and all updated versions of vue and typescript.
So I'm using library [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/) and as I follow documentation and write in any file  either ts or vue, does not matter if it's in composition api or not, I always have same error.
So it looks like that

I'm trying to get some value of storage like so:

> const toke = useStorage('my-store', '');

and after I want to do some with it like:

```
console.log(toke.value)
```

and it's always returning

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Pick<Ref, unique
> symbol>'.

Why is that? As I see, everything is good with library, but that is not working.

Also I tried with other functions, and useSessionStorage is not working as well, but useNow is good.

Comment: Which lib version? In case it's not the latest, did you try to update it?

Comment: It is the new one :/

Comment: What is TS version? I don't see how this error could occur, at least for up-to-date TS. useStorage type is simple but will likely fail for TS < 4. Does the error occur in IDE or compilation? Can you provide a way to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Well, TypeScript is ~4.1.5

Comment: @RadeIliev I cannot reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vueuse-usestorage-issue?file=src%2FApp.vue). Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: I could not, but I have added my file there.